# Why does the method telephonyManager.getVoiceNetworkType() return the value for Network_LTE even when Wi-Fi call is enabled?

Tags: java, android

My application uses telephonyManager to check the type of network the voice call is carried over. The test is to confirm that calls are being carried over Wifi. However, the printed result from the app is not what I expect, even during calls.

```
int voiceNetworkTypeVal = 0;
voiceNetworkTypeVal = telephonyManager.getVoiceNetworkType();
```

However, when I call the phone over Wifi and run the app, the phone always prints voiceNetworkTypeVal as int value 13, NETWORK_TYPE_LTE, instead of the expected value 18 (NETWORK_TYPE_IWLAN) for wifi calls. Anyone knows how to fix this?